# How do I find and replace 'nil' values of Ruby hash with "None" or 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, null

I'm trying to drill down to each value in an iteration of an array nested hash and replace all `nil` values with something like 'None' or 0. Please see my code that is clearly not working. I need to fix this before I pass it to my Views in Rails for iteration and rendering:

My controller:

```
def show
  results = Record.get_record(params[:trans_uuid])
  if !results.empty?
    record = results.map { |res| res.attributes.symbolize_keys }
    @record = Record.replace_nil(record) # this calls method in Model
  else
    flash[:error] = 'No record found'
  end
end
```

My model:

```
def self.replace_nil(record)
  record.each do |r|
    r.values == nil ? "None" : r.values
  end
end
```

`record` looks like this when passed to Model method `self.replace_nil(record`:

```
[{:id=>1, :time_inserted=>Wed, 03 Apr 2019 15:41:06 UTC +00:00, :time_modified=>nil, :request_state=>"NY", :trans_uuid=>"fe27813c-561c-11e9-9284-0282b642e944", :sent_to_state=>-1, :completed=>-1, :record_found=>-1, :retry_flag=>-1, :chargeable=>-1, :note=>"", :bridge_resultcode=>"xxxx", :bridge_charges=>-1}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure the reason to do that, but it sounds like you could just handle the case when it's nil on the view (maybe a view helper). You are formating values on the controller, sounds like something that belongs to the view (you can do `@record[:time_modified] || 'None'` for example)

Comment: `.each` should only be used when you only want the side effects and don't care about the return value. Like in a view where each iteration prints to the buffer.

Comment: As @arieljuod stated, it'd be nice to see what's the case you have here, and maybe there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: For an Array you could do something like this: `my_array.map{ |value| value || "None" }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`each` won't "persist" the value you're yielding within the block. Try `map` instead.

```
def self.replace_nil(record) 
  record.map do |r| 
    r.values.nil? ? "None" : r.values
  end 
end
```

In fact, there's a method for that; `transform_values`:

```
record.transform_values do |value|
   value.nil? ? 'None' : value
end
```

---

I realized that using Rails you can use just `presence` and the `or` operator:

```
record.transform_values do |value|
  value.presence || 'None'
end
```

Comment: Also `deep_transform_values` if you need it for all the nested elements.