# How to replace nil and 'empty string' with "None" in Ruby/Rails in enumerable object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash, enums

I'm taking to objects in Rails: a Record::ActiveRecord_Relation and a ActionController::Parameters and turn them into usable Hashes to be rendered in Views. I need to replace nil and "" with "none". I could do it the non-dry way and protect every key/value pair of the Hash with something like:

```
  <div><%= @records_incoming[:time_inserted] || @records_incoming[:time_inserted].empty? ? "none" : @records_incoming[:time_inserted]  %></div>
```

but that doesn't seem very Ruby like (granted, I'm a newer developer).

I've tried to handle this in the controller like so:

```
def show
    sent_results = Record.get_sent(params[:request][:trans_uuid]) 

    if !sent_results.empty? 

      incoming_request = params[:request].permit!
      @records_sent = sent_results[0].attributes.each { |k,v| v.class == String && v.empty? || !v ? sent_results[0].attributes[k] = "none" : sent_results[0].attributes[k] } 
      @records_incoming = incoming_request.to_h.map { |k, v| v.empty? || !v ? "none" : v }
      byebug 
    else    
      flash[:error] = 'No record found'
    end 
  end
```

but this does not change the nil and empty string values to 'none'. If I use `map`, I of course get an array as the return value but I need to retain a Hash.

Please advise on any better Rails ways to do this overall. Trying to get 2 hashes into views to be split out and rendered.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241397/how-do-i-find-and-replace-nil-values-of-ruby-hash-with-none-or-0?

Comment: Wow I think you're right. My brain is scrambled these days. I think I also got caught up in trying to deal with 2 different type of objects and trying to normalize them before they hit Views.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`presence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence).

```
<%= @records_incoming[:time_inserted].presence || "none" %>
```

It handles the two cases you need, `@records_incoming[:time_inserted]` being nil or an empty string as it returns the receiver if it's `present?`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform_values!` on params hash

try,

```
incoming_request.transform_values! { |v| v.empty? || !v ? "none" : v }
@records_incoming = incoming_request
```

Ref: [transform_values! doc](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/transform_values%21)

Note: `transform_values!` updates the hash in place